# Grails Job | Multiple updates in mongodb always throw optimistic locking exception, how to handle it?

Tags: mongodb, grails, optimistic-locking

i have a grails job which is scheduled to run at every night, to update stats of all user which are firstOrderDate, lastOrderDate and totalOrders.

Have a look at the code.

```
 void updateOrderStatsForAllUsers(DateTime date) {
    List<Order> usersByOrders = Delivery.findAllByDeliveryDateAndStatus(date, "DELIVERED")*.order
    List<User> customers = usersByOrders*.customer.unique()

    for (User u in customers) {
        List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
        orders = u.orders?.findAll { it.status.equals("DELIVERED") }?.sort { it?.dateCreated }
        if (orders?.size() > 0) {
            u.firstOrderDate = orders?.first()?.dateCreated
            u.lastOrderDate = orders?.last()?.dateCreated
            u.totalOrders = orders.size()
            u.save(flush: true)
        }
    }
}
```

and the job that runs this code is

```
def execute(){
    long jobStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

    emailService.sendJobStatusEmail(JOB_NAME, "STARTED", 0, null)

    try {
        // Daily job for updating user orders
        DateTime yesterday = new DateTime().withZone(DateTimeZone.getDefault()).withTimeAtStartOfDay().minusDays(1)
        userService.updateOrderStatsForAllUsers(yesterday)
        emailService.sendJobStatusEmail(JOB_NAME, "FINISHED", jobStartTime, null)
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        emailService.sendJobStatusEmail(JOB_NAME, "FAILED", jobStartTime, e)
    }
}
```

So i am sending a mail , for any exception that occurs , now the issue is i always get a failure mail of "Error: OptimisticLockingException" at u.save(). For a date i have around 400 users.

I know why optimistic locking happens , but as you can see i am not updating the same user record in loop instead , i have a list of different users and i am iterating them to update all of them. Then how come i get an optimistic locking exception at user save. help !

Comment: I wonder if the default comparator used by unique() is not suitable for your domain class. What's the code for your User domain class?

Answer (score 0):

Optimistic locking is a hibernate error and Mango DB has nothing to do with this.

What entity is throwing optimistic locking exception is it customer or order or delivery?

How do you ensure none of these entities are getting updated elsewhere in the app when this job is running?

How do you ensure this job is getting triggered only once at a time?

Try to add some logging to see it's a repeatable issue by triggering the job again once the previous execution has completed.

More debugging may help resolve the issue.

Comment: Answers for your question
1- the entity throwing optimistic locking is customer definitely, because the logs of error stack-trace are sent in mail and it always shows the line 20 which is u.save in my case.
2- Also, none of the entity updates at that time since the job runs in morning 4am , when no other job is scheduled, and no other process can take place, since the platform is only available in day time for users.
3- the crone expression is what made it to trigger only once at every day at 4

Comment: Error on u.save() does not mean error is on customer entity.  Check the stack trace in detail this could be any connected entity with the ID availble in exception log. Once again I would suggest to add some extra debugging statements to ensure there's no parallel processing going on with your code or the quartz job.

Answer (score 0):

the quartz jobs usually do not provide the TX-context for it's operations, so you should wrap your method into a transaction by hand:

```
def execute(){
  ...
  User.withTransaction{ tx -> 
        userService.updateOrderStatsForAllUsers(yesterday)
  }
  ....
}
```

Comment: i have tried this approach in updateOrderStatsForAllUsers, i have enclosed the for loop for updating all users in User.withTransaction { } , but it didn't worked. should it be in job file itself ?

Comment: usually the service methods are wrapped in a transaction by default. The job doesn't provide it. so yes, you have to do it in the job